# Why only the first printf is outputted to the terminal?

Tags: c

I have a C program where I define and use my own `printf()` function. However, only the first `printf`, i.e. `printf("Hello World 1\n");` is outputted. But why?

```c
int printf(const char *__restrict __format, ...);

int printf(const char *__restrict __format, ...) {}

int main() {
    printf("Hello World 1\n");
    printf("Hello World %d\n", 2);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
Hello World 1
```

But I don't understand why

Comment: Are you using the compiler gcc? Does the behavior change if you compile with the `-fno-builtin` command-line option?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am using gcc, and both printf are not outputed after adding the `-fno-builtin` option.

Comment: `printf("Hello World 1\n");` assumes the build it standard function and so the _optimized_ print.   `printf("Hello World %d\n", 2);` calls OP's empty function.

Answer (score 8):

According to [§7.1.3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3), the identifier `printf` is reserved for use by the standard library. This applies even if you do not include the header file, because the identifier has [external linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). Therefore, as far as the ISO C standard is concerned, your program is invoking undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen, including the behavior you describe.

However, if you are asking why specifically the compiler gcc behaves this way, then the answer is a bit more complex, because the compiler gcc has its own rules:

In gcc, the function `printf` is a [built-in function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins). This allows the compiler to optimize the line

```
printf("Hello World 1\n");
```

to:

```
puts("Hello World 1");
```

It does not perform this optimization on `printf` calls with more than one argument, so the line

```
printf("Hello World %d\n", 2);
```

does not get optimized to `puts`.

Therefore, your posted code effectively gets compiled to the following:

```
int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...) {}

int main() {
    puts("Hello World 1");
    printf("Hello World %d\n", 2);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to prevent gcc from optimizing `printf` calls to `puts` calls, then you can use the [`-fno-builtin`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno-builtin) command-line option to prevent gcc from recognizing functions as built-in, or `-fno-builtin-printf` to only prevent the `printf` function from being recognized as built-in. Note that even if you use these options, you can still explicitly call the built-in versions of these functions by using the `__builtin_` prefix, for example `__builtin_printf`.